# How to add return values of a function in C

Tags: c, sum, return-value

Any ideas on how to add the sum of all the values that are returned from a function?

I need to add individual digits of a long integer together. I have figured out how to isolate and print each digit I need, but I don't know how I should set up the code to return those digits to in order to add them together.

Comment: Return a structure containing a dynamically-allocated array of numbers and the count of elements.

Comment: You initialize a local variable (e.g. `total`) to `0`. Then you go over each of the digits, but instead of printing them, you add the value of that digit to the `total`. When you have done all digits, you simply `return total;`.

Comment: Looks like XY-problem. Do you really want to split a number and return all digits in one function and sum digits in another? It is overhead, you can sum them instantly.

Comment: I can't tell if you have a `char sum[]` and need to create a long, or if you need to generate that `sum` from a `long inputs[]`, fixed number of arguments or a perhaps variable argument list.  Add some code to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int SumOfDigits(long x)
{
    int sum;
    for(sum=0; x; x/=10) sum += x%10;
    return sum;
}


int main(void) {
    long x = 12345678;
    printf("Sum of Digits of %lu is %d\n", x, SumOfDigits(x));
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5420KB
Sum of Digits of 12345678 is 36
```

Because:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36
```